# How can I control my image in html using css style?

Tags: html, css, image

I've tried to insert an image in my html page then i had a problem which is once i scroll down, the image covers the nav bar and the logo of my page.

Comment: @chouneyou thanks a lot that was helpful, it helped me to solve my problem

Comment: Please include code when asking questions. I recommend that you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please share what css and html you wrote? Not sure what kind of effect you would like to achieve.

1. If you wanna your image simply below other elements:

   img{
   z-index:-1;
   }
2. If you have other combination to go for,
   play with the properties: positions and display:
   [CSS Layout - The position Property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)
   [CSS Display](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)